# Can the device on the other end of a socket change without me knowing?

Tags: authentication, ip, .net

I have a server application written in C#. I am currently authenticating the client whenever a socket is opened, before sending any other Data. After the client is authenticated I assume it's always the same client using this socket. Is this safe or can another person "take over" the Socket after it's authenticated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a simple UDP or TCP socket all the information which are needed to take over the connection are visible in plain on any system in the middle. This means a man in the middle could fully take over the connection after it was established or even just put itself inside the connection and forward modified data to the original peer.

But if the application protocol has an internal state which can not be derived by the attacker from interceptable information then such a take over is not possible. This is for example true if SSL/TLS is used on top of TCP. In this case a man in the middle attack is no longer practical. But an attacker on the endpoint itself might for example inject its own code into a running application and thus control what data get transferred over the socket.

Man in the middle attacks are also not possible if the attacker can not sniff the plain UDP or TCP connection. This can be achieved by protecting the communication path at lower layers, for example with IPSec or other VPN technologies. But attacks at the endpoint itself are still possible in these cases too.